# Self join queries in hive

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, self-join

I need a hive query to fetch the hierarchy in which my product was sold . 
Considering the below records , the end customer was 1 and 6 , since their SoldTo column value is NULL.

```
CustomerID  SoldTo
--------------------
1             NULL
2             1
3             2
4             3
5             4
6             NULL
7             1
8             6
```

My output should look like :

```
c1  c2  c3  c4  c5
-------------------
5   4   3   2   1   (c1 (5) - first customer who bought product and c5(1) -last customer)
8   6               (c1 (8) - first customer , c2 (6)- Last customer)       
7   1
```

Answer (score 0):

Hive has no real support for recursive CTEs or hierarchical data structures.  You can do this using multiple joins -- but the depth of the hierarchy is fixed.

```
select t1.CustomerId as c1, t2.CustomerId as c2, t3.CustomerId as c3,
       t4.CustomerId as c4, t5.CustomerId
from t t1 left join
     t t2
     on t2.SoldTo = t1.CustomerId left join
     t t3
     on t3.SoldTo = t2.CustomerId left join
     t t4
     on t4.SoldTo = t3.CustomerId left join
     t t5
     on t5.SoldTo = t4.CustomerId     
where t1.CustomerId is null;
```

Comment: The depth of the hierarchy cannot be predicted. And yes your solution would work if the depth is fixed.

Comment: @JohnThomas . . . As explained in the answer.